# How to adopt an Obj-C protocol with one property in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have this Obj-C protocol

```
@protocol MSOutlineViewControllerModelInterface
@property   (weak)  MSOutlineViewController *fatherController ;
@end
```

I have this swift class

```
class ModelFileTree : NSObject, MSOutlineViewControllerModelInterface
{
    @objc   weak var fatherController   : MSOutlineViewController?
}
```

And the compiler keeps telling me "Type ModelFileTree does not conform to protocol 'MSOutlineViewControllerModelInterface'... I can't figure any way out...

Comment: This compiles just fine for me. Are there any more details from the error message?

Comment: Well, if I go to the detail of the error, I have 2 sentences :
1 - Protocol requires property 'fatherController' with type 'MSOutlineViewController?' (aka 'Optional<MSOutlineViewController>')
2 - Candidate has non-matching type 'MSOutlineViewController?' (aka 'Optional<MSOutlineViewController>')
To me this looks exactly like what I did...

Comment: Still not understood, but a hint : if I replace MSOutlineViewController by any other class (well, I tried with 3 other classes), it compiles...

MSOutlineViewController is defined as :
@interface MSOutlineViewController : NSViewController

Comment: Double check your Obj-C bridging header to make sure MSOutlineViewController is imported correctly

Comment: I did, and it is... I really run out of ideas

Comment: You might try cleaning, rebuilding, and deleting Derived Data. Just in case there is something wrong during compilation.

Comment: Still not... thanks for your support, but I'm giving up there. I am of course still in the learning curve of Swift, but I'm going 10 times faster doing things in Obj-C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because it is comparing `MSOutlineViewController` to `MSOutlineViewController?`, which are different in Swift.

Try this:

```
@protocol MSOutlineViewControllerModelInterface
    @property   (weak)  MSOutlineViewController * _Nullable fatherController ;
@end
```

Comment: Good try, but that does not solve the problem... Symptoms are still the same